# How do I print a long decimal number in c?

Tags: c, long-double

I need the program to print "0.03571428". Instead my program prints only 0.035714. Sorry for the stupid question but I am a beginner as you can see!

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        long double a;
        int b = 1, c = 28;
         a = (long double) b / (long double) c;    
        printf("%Lf", a);
        return 0;

}
```

Comment: `print("%0.10f", a)`

Answer (score 3):

The `%f` format specifier prints 6 digits after the decimal point by default.  To change that, add a precision modifier specifying the number of digits:

```
printf("%.8Lf", a);
```